# Updating project that extends a class removed in dependency project

Tags: dependency-management, pharo, monticello, metacello

Imagine that you have a package `MyPackage` and it depends on another project called `Library`. `MyPackage` has extension methods in a class `LibraryClass` which is in the `Library` project.

At some point `Library` is changed and `LibraryClass` is renamed to `NewLibraryClass` or removed completely. You make changes in your project, for example move extension methods to `NewLibraryClass` or solve it in a different way, this does not matter much.

The problem arises when someone has a pre-`Library`-changes version of `MyPackage` already installed and updates it. Then `Library` package is loaded first, as your project depends on it. While `Library` is being loaded `LibraryClass` is removed and so `MyPackage` extension methods that were present in `LibraryClass` are deleted. This marks `MyPackage` as dirty, and so when it finally loads changes to `MyPackage`, the user is asked to resolve a merge even if there are no real conflicts.

How can this be solved? Because in the end your code is fine, but the user that updates your project will face weird merge questions.

Comment: The only way I see to cope with this properly is for every project to keep track of (i.e., remember) all classes whose names have changed and offer services that dependent projects could use to migrate themselves when loading.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hack that should not be qualified as a full solution, but helps to overcome the issue.

In the configuration of your project add a pre-load doit (section 1.10 of [Managing projects with Metacello](http://pharobyexample.org/drafts/Metacello.pdf)) and call this method:

```
cleanUpLibrary

  | myPackage |

  myPackage := (#MyPackage asPackageIfAbsent: [ ^ self ]).

  LibraryClass asClassIfPresent: [ :class |
    class protocols
      select: [ :prot | prot asLowercase beginsWith: myPackage methodCategoryPrefix ]
      thenDo: [ :prot | class removeProtocol: prot ] ].

  myPackage mcWorkingCopy modified: false
```

This will remove all extension protocols of `MyPackage` from `LibraryClass` and mark `MyPackage` as not modified (clean, not dirty…). Then when `Library` will be loading and will remove `LibraryClass`, `MyPackage` will not be marked as dirty, because at that moment `LibraryClass` will not have any extension methods of `MyPackage`